# Low flash memory in Android ZTE phone

Tags: storage

In my Android ZTE, I'm trying to upload things. Let's say, I'm uploading a resume, I will get a message saying it can't be delivered due to low memory.

I have deleted things like games and pictures that I thought consumed my memory, but still, I get that message.

How do I increase my phone's free flash memory?

Answer (score 2):

Upload fails when destination storage limit exceeded, which is most likely not related to your storage. Anyway, there is no way to increase flash memory.

Without root permissions you can "clear cache" from app settings. youtube and chrome are good candidates.

With root access you can do a little more, but at least external MicroSD Card is required